# Is there an "Arrested Development" reference in "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, easter-egg

In *Infinity War*, you see a corpse that looks like Tobias Fünke when he blue himself, 
[image]

and in *Civil War*, the Bluth staircar was in the background of the airport.
[image]

Both of those movies were directed by the Russo brothers, and they did *Endgame* as well, so is there a reference there as well?

Comment: Found this for you... https://news.avclub.com/yep-theres-an-arrested-development-character-hidden-in-1825618581

Comment: There are at least two actors who appear in both *Endgame* and *Arrested Development*: the security guard at the storage facility where Ant Man, uh, shows up; and the lady in the elevator at Camp Lehigh. But neither of them seems to be playing the same character in both, so I'm not sure they qualify as references.

Comment: @Martha they were both in *Arrested Development* as well as *Community*?

Comment: @Martha Ken Jeong and Yvette Nicole Brown were not actually in Arrested Development, they were in Endgame because the Russos also worked with them on Community. https://www.looper.com/151348/avengers-endgame-easter-eggs-you-missed/

Comment: I suspect not; if there were, someone would have posted about it by now. Maybe someone should just reply "No." so the question is no longer unanswered. :)

Comment: Would [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieDetails/comments/cn7qlf/in_avengers_endgame_2019_in_the_therapy_group/) be considered an “Arrested Development” reference?

Comment: @fez that's an Easter Egg for someone who worked on the film. I wouldn't really call that an Arrested Development reference.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - agreed, that's definitely scraping the bottom of the barrel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No.

Based on the amazing research efforts of the commenters on the question, I would say it's at least a semi-conclusive no. [Credit to Mark Reed for pointing out; we don't need to sit here waiting for a positive answer when there isn't one.] Sorry to the asker of the question - it's a good one, and I upvoted - but there doesn't seem to be one. (I did my own research and there were definitely some in the other movies, and I'm told there's one in *Guardians of the Galaxy* if anyone wants to look.)

Comment: No is an answer, and after these long many years I’ll accept it

Comment: Thanks! Glad that it finally has one. I've gotten tired of seeing it on the "unanswered" page and set out to do something about it; so I spent the last hour researching it. You're welcome for the answer!